# Is there Custom User Data equivalent for Locations / Organizations in CommCare?

Tags: commcare

Is there an equivalent to Custom User Data for Locations / Organizations in CommCare?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes there is.
From the *Manage Organization Structure* web interface page you can use the *edit locations* button to access what is essentially the same interface as the Custom User Data.  After you create the structure you can then update the data one at a time through the web interface (accessed by drilling down into your Organizations structure and then choosing "edit") or in bulk via the excel upload process (again, the same as the Custom User Data interface).